# Show $(N, ≤)$ is a partial order with least upper bounds (lubs) and greatest lower bounds (glbs) of all pairs.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, upper-lower-bounds, natural-numbers

does anyone have any solution or a *good* hint?

Let $(\mathbb{N}, ≤)$ be the set of natural numbers with the relation $m ≤ n$, meaning $m$ divides $n$. Show $(\mathbb{N}, ≤)$ is a partial order with least upper bounds (lubs) and greatest lower bounds (glbs) of all pairs. What are these lubs and glbs in
more traditional terms? If $\mathbb{N}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Z}$, does the divides
relation still yield a partial order?

Ok, this is what I got:

I have the set of all divisors for n,  $(N,≤)=(m_1,…,m_k│m_i  divides n)$,where $i=1,2,…,k$. In order for $(N,≤)$ to be of partial order it need to be: reflexive (each element is comparable to itself), antisymmetric (no two different elements precede each other and transitive (the start of a chain of precedence relations must precede the end of the chain).

Reflexive: $m_i$  divides $m_i$

Antisymmetric:if $m_i |m_j$,where $i≠j$,then $m_j∤m_i$ since $m_j$ must be greater than $m_i$.

Transitive:if $m_i|m_j$ and $m_j|m_k$, then $m_i|m_j*q=m_k$ for some $q∈N$.

Here is where it gets tricky. I'm reasoning like this:

Take any pair say m_i and m_j, then I have the union of the set of all divisors for m_i and the set of all divisors for m_j. The union is not empty, because it contains 1, and every non-empty subset of the natural number has a least member. Also, any common divisor c satisfies c≤m_i and c≤m_j, so the set has a greatest member. The greatest member has to be the least upper bound since the union of divisors is finite. 1 must always be a lower bound of the union since 1 is less than or equal to all elements in the union. It must also be the greatest lower bound since 1 is the greatest lower bound for the natural numbers (and the union is a subset, containing 1, of the natural numbers).

I'm sure this is wrong, help please.

Comment: What about greatest common divisor and least common multiple?

Comment: Ok, I'm doing something wrong. I can prove that it is of partial order. But then I think I'm out of my league.

Take any pair say m_i and m_j, then I have the union of the set of all divisors for m_i and m_j. The union is not empty, because it contains 1. Also, any common divisor c satisfies c≤m_i and c≤m_j, so the set has a greatest member. The greatest member has to be the least upper bound since the union of divisors is finite. 1 must always be a lower bound of the union since 1 is less than or equal to all elements in the union.

Comment: Why don't you start by thinking about some concrete case, say $m_1-6$ and $m_2=10$? What are the lower bounds and the upper bounds for the set $\{m_1,m_2\}$?

Comment: Do you mean $m_1 = 6$? 

I'm so lost, lol.

Comment: Picking on bof's comment, what are the divisors of 6? and what are the divisors of 10? Is there one which is larger than the others (in the sense that it is multiple of the others)? If so, it is the greatest lower bound (hint: it is also the greatest common divisor; see my comment above). Do the same for multiples. Is there a smaller one (perhaps the least common multiple)? If so, it is the least upper bound. Generalize for other pairs.

Comment: Also please read about lattices - `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)`

Answer (score 1):

I'll continue the good example, given by @bof. Let's consider the pair $\{6, 10\}$.

1. **GLB**. All the divisors of $6$ are $\{1,2,3,6\}$. All the divisors of $10$ are $\{1,2,5,10\}$. *Intersection* (by the way, you wrote *union* in your question) of these two sets will give you a set $\{1,2\}$ of all the *lower bounds*. Then you can choose $2$ as the *greatest lower bound*, because $1\le2$ (but not because $1$ is less than $2$ in arithmetical sense). Note now that $GCD(6,10)=2$.
2. **LUB**. Number of all the *upper bounds* for the pair $\{6,10\}$ is infinite, but you can choose a most evident one - $60$, because it's a product of $6$ and $10$. However it won't be the least one. You need to represent both $6$ and $10$ as products of *prime factors*. So, $6=2\cdot3$ and $10=2\cdot5$. The *least upper bound*, represented as product of prime factors, **must** contain all the prime factors of $6$ and $10$ - so we get $30=2\cdot3\cdot5$. Note now that $LCM(6,10)=30$.

The picture below shows a piece of the [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) $(N,\le)$, where partial order is induced by divisibility:

[image: Lattice]

And now you need to generalize all this for *any* pair of natural numbers - good luck!

As for your second question about the $\mathbb{Z}$ - please think about antisymmetry axiom. If $(-n)$ divides $n$ and $n$ divides $(-n)$, then what?